# Finding characters in a sentence

Tags: c

I want to make a program that can find characters in long string...
.
.

```
int i = 0;
char buf[100];
char ch[10];
char *res;
int len = 0;
int j = 0;

printf("Enter characters: ");
while(1){
    j = getchar();
    if(j == '\n') break;
    ch[i++] = j;
}
ch[i] = '\0';

while(len < 1){
    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    res = fgets(buf, 200, stdin);
    len = strlen(buf);
}
```

Here's sample execute screen.

Enter characters: mkn

Enter a sentence: My son is in elementary school.

Finding..

-
My
son
in

### elementary

I want to make this program with strtok() and strchr()... but I am confused with pointers....

Comment: Why do you want to use `strtok` and `strchr`?

Comment: Could you be clearer to describe your need ? You say _that can find characters_ and the sample result is **My son in**. The function `strtok()` is used to extract words between delimiters and the `strchr()` is able to look the first position of one character in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Though they may not be the best choices for this purpose, you can achieve what you want with `strtok()` and `strchr()`.  Below is how I picture building on what you already have to get a working solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define CHARACTERS_MAXIMUM 32
#define BUFFER_MAXIMUM 1024

int main() {
    char characters[CHARACTERS_MAXIMUM];
    int characters_length = 0, character;

    printf("Enter characters: ");

    while (characters_length < CHARACTERS_MAXIMUM - 1) {
        character = getchar();
        if (character == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        characters[characters_length++] = tolower(character);
        characters[characters_length++] = toupper(character);
    }
    characters[characters_length] = '\0';

    char buffer[BUFFER_MAXIMUM], *result = NULL;
    int buffer_length = 0;

    while (buffer_length < 1 || result == NULL) {
        printf("Enter a sentence: ");

        if ((result = fgets(buffer, BUFFER_MAXIMUM, stdin)) != NULL) {
            buffer_length = strlen(buffer);
        }
    }

    char *token = strtok(buffer, " ");

    while (token != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < characters_length; i++) {
            if (strchr(token, characters[i]) != NULL) {
                printf("%s ", token);
                break;
            }
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is not a finished program, there's more/better error checking you should do as well as other tweaks to finish it off properly.

**USAGE EXAMPLE**

```
> ./a.out
Enter characters: mkn
Enter a sentence: My son is in elementary school.
My son in elementary 
>
```

Although the above is an appropriate use of `strtok()`, be wary of it. It is an artifact of an earlier age and should be avoided in favor of safer, modern library functions like `strsep()` or `strtok_r()`.